# D3 How to access data of an object in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, d3.js

My goal is to access the datas for a diagramm via a function out of an object.

I saved the object in a a variable: `countries`.

```
Object {Belgium: Array[5], Bulgaria: Array[5], Denmark: Array[5], Germany: Array[5]…}

Belgium : Array[5]
0 : 7030385
1 : 7455142
2 : 7545539
3 : 7644818
4 : 8002186
```

I want to access the data via a function. But somewhere is a mistake. The diagram is always empty

```
var diagram = svg.selectAll("circle").data(countries).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return x(years[i]); })
  .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return y(d.Belgium[i]); })
  .attr("r", 2);
})
```

Comment: Could you post a working example?

Comment: What do you mean by "working example"? The entire code? Because the example above is not working, thats why asked how to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now. Was as i thought just a little switch in the code ...

```
var diagram = svg.selectAll("circle").data(countries[Belgium]).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return x(years[i]); })
  .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return y(d); })
  .attr("r", 2);
})
```